# How to change the position of Short Description in Front End?

Tags: magento2, frontend

I want to change the position of short description to below the price.

[image: I need to show the short description below the price]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this

1. **Go to the below location**

> `Magento_root/app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/`

Open the file with name `catalog_product_view.xml` put the below code there

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      <body>
         <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Save the file & refresh the front-end

2. **Go to the below location**

> Magento_root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout

Copy the file with name `catalog_product_view.xml` And paste it at the below location

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/

Search for the below code there

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.price">
```

And replace it with the below code

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.price">
```

Save the file & refresh the front-end

> Note- While you are doing this,do not forget to **disable the cache** or
>   **run the below command** from your **Magento_root**
>
> ```
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```

Comment: app>design>frontend>Magento here its empty. How to do it?

Comment: you need to create your new custom theme & in your custom theme you need to find this `catalog_product_view.xml` file as the directed path

Comment: If you don't want to create your own theme then you can do it by putting this `<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price" />` code into the design section of every product from your admin section but this will increase your data entry stuff more so better would be create your own theme

Answer (score 1):

only adding this in your layout file (`catalog_product_view.xml`) make it work

```
...    
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="page.main.title" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your **catalog_product_view.xml** file.

```
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price" />
```

Comment: Can you tell me the path where I can find this .xml file?

Comment: In your theme's layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

Magento core structure changes

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.price">
```

Magento Theme structure changes

> /app/design/frontend/Cloudways/m2-theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.price">
```

[image]